# Start an app within another app Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, firebase-dynamic-links

My question is how to start app A within app B that appears app A is within app B through deep linking?

In the first picture below, the Debug app appears as a separate app from Slack (new code, Firebase deep linking). In the 2nd picture, the Debug app appears to be within the Slack app (old code, Android deep linking). I want to use Firebase deep linking and show the Debug app within other apps (Slack, Gmail etc).

[image][image]

Can anyone please go through my code below and let me know how I can achieve this?

## Old code, Android deep linking:

**AndroidManifest**

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.SplashScreenActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "abc://flights” -->
        <data
            android:host="sales"
            android:scheme="abc" />
        <data
            android:host="deals"
            android:scheme="abc" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Activity:**

Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, BottomNavBarActivity.class);

```
        //Deep Linking Content
        Uri deepLinkData = getIntent().getData();
        if (deepLinkData != null) {
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEEP_LINK, deepLinkData.getHost());
        }

        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.splash_fade_in, R.anim.splash_fade_out);
        finish();
```

## New Code, Firebase deep linking:

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="abc.app.goo.gl"
                android:scheme="http"/>
            <data
                android:host="abc.app.goo.gl"
                android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Activity:**

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                    Uri deepLink = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {

                    // Start the activity through intent, same as before.

                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Firebase deep link failure");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its dependent on the app which sends the intent, for example whether they pass `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` or not. I suspect the difference here is how Slack is handling the links - they may treat web URLs differently than other format ones (your old links have non-standard schemes).

Comment: Thanks Ian. I guess it's possible Slack handle web URLs or other format ones differently. I haven't been able to open the other format ones on apps other than Slack. Not sure how other apps will handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method openApp(), and call it accorrding to your need.

```
public void openAnApp()
    {
      Boolean flag=false;
      try{
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           intent.setType("text/plain");  
           final PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
           Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
           intent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
           List<ResolveInfo> resInfos = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent1, 0);
           ActivityInfo activity = null;
           //getting package names and adding them to the hashset
           for(ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfos) {
            System.out.println("apap="+resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
            if(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.equals("your.app.packagename"))
            {  
                flag = true;
                activity = resolveInfo.activityInfo; 
                break;
            }
         }
           if (flag) { 
           //  final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo; 
               final ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,activity.name);
               intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
               intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
               intent.setComponent(name);
               getActivity().startActivity(intent);
               //startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent , "Send image using.."));
              } else {
                  Uri uri=Uri.parse("market://details?id=your.app.packagename");
                Intent goToMarket=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
                try{
                    startActivity(goToMarket);
                }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){                    
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Couldn't launch the market",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
              }
             } catch (Exception e) {
              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It started the app but it was not within the parent app. Plus, this code is supposed to be used for deep linking, not just starting the app. Thanks anyway.